# Using "about" to begin your answer

Tags: grammaticality

> "What are you writing about?"
> "About my favourite TV programme."

Does this about make sense at the start of the answer? I think that it makes sense but isn't used in natural, everyday English (at least where I'm from). Personally, I would use "I'm writing about my favourite TV programme" or just "My favourite TV programme". Is this regional? No longer used frequently today, but common in the past?

Thank you for your responses in advance

Comment: No, it isn't used in idiomatic English.

Comment: The only reason the cited reply can start with ***About*** is because of the context established by the question - which allows the responder to "delete" initial ***I am writing** [about blah blah]*. But this is just normal use of *any* language, nothing to do with English, regional variation, or changes over time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verbless sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143488/verbless-sentence)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - when we did 'comprehension' exercises in junior school (age 7 to 11) - suppose we read a piece about Guy Fawkes and one of the questions was 'Why was Guy Fawkes put to death?', we would get a poor mark for answering 'Because he tried to blow up Parliament'. We had to write 'Guy Fawkes was put to to death because he tried to blow up Parliament'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Dang! Your school sounds even tougher than *The School of Hard Knocks!* But are we trying to teach people how to speak / write English, or how to pass (utterly pointless, imho) ***exams***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - now they probably write 'Because gunpowder', and get top marks.

Comment: I'm sure to the average 10-year-old, *Bonfire Night* is more about *fireworks* than Guy Fawkes (same as *Christmas* is motre about *presents* than Christ). Because "progress"? Or because "social decay / breakdown"?